# Getting root domain SSL to work with G Suite, Google Sites, and Google Domains

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, google-classic-sites, https, dns, ssl

I have Google's G Suite newly hooked up to a domain I'll call example.com

I have a Google Sites (a new-Google-Sites site) at an address like this:
`https://sites.google.com/example.com/example`

I have the domain example.com held at Google Domains

I followed the directions [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7392423?hl=en):

And set up custom url via the G Suite Admin panel such that
`https://www.example.com` --> `https://sites.google.com/example.com/example`

It works through a CNAME record as described in the answer above:

```
www CNAME ghs.googlehosted.com
```

**Right now** typing *any* of the following into the browser ends up correctly showing the site (via `https://www.example.com/`):

- `http://www.example.com/`
- `http://example.com/`
- `example.com`
- `https://www.example.com`

**BUT** typing `https://example.com` **does not work**, and does not resolve or redirect to anything. I get this:

[image: error message]

How do I configure this correctly?

Comment: Note: [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2518373) and [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2579934) are not the answer for this particular problem

Comment: Posting [this answer](https://www.tachyonstemplates.com/2018/google-domains-forward-root/) from @blairanderson - it solved it

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs to [webmasters.se] and [sf].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://www.tachyonstemplates.com/2018/google-domains-forward-root/) from @blairanderson solved it:

[image: blair anderson's answer]

Comment: I'm accepting this in lieu of a post from Blair Anderson. If Blair Anderson posts the answer, I'll de-accept this one and delete it.

Answer (score 3):

I have hosted several websites using Google Sites, that includes sites for educational institutions, local shops, and personal websites.

First off, **you can't use a naked domain to get to work with your site on Google sites**. It must have a subdomain, be it www or blahblah or whatever.

What you can do however is you can forward http://example.com or https://example.com to https://www.example.com or any subdomain that you chose. **GSuite has an option to forward naked domain to your www site**. However, I prefer doing it through Cloudflare. There are several reasons to like Cloudflare: it gives you a decent DNS management system which propagates fast, provides a CDN, and others.

If you want to use Cloudflare, here are the steps that you should follow:

1. Go to page rules. Set a parmanent redirect

   > domain.com/* to
   >
   > https://www.domain.com/$1
2. Remember to put **SSL/TLS encryption mode** to **Full (strict)**
3. It is essential to have your A records pointed somewhere. Even Google's or Blogger's IP addresses are fine. Most often I use the four IP addresses used for Blogger, which are

   > 216.239.32.21
   >
   > 216.239.34.21
   >
   > 216.239.36.21
   >
   > 216.239.38.21

Infact, there are many good reference to using Cloudflare for Google Sites on Cloudflare community. Not an endorsement but [Here is one which I have bookmarked](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/naked-domain-doesnt-redirect-even-after-setting-page-rules/183384) to check things quickly if I forget.